# Dependcy conflict NextJs 12.2.5 and next-auth 4.17

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.17.0
npm ERR! node_modules/next-auth
npm ERR!   next-auth@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
this is still an issue and downgrading did not help as much

i totally removed my node-modules and package-lock file even use the --force flag while trying to install next-auth but still the dependcy conflict persist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing with '--legacy-peer-deps'  flag, It usually solve this kind of problems for me